# Cannot open `pg_hba.conf` in pgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-hba.conf

I am running:

```
version
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 9.4.11 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

and:

```
pgAdmin III 1.22.2
```

on the same:

```
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release: 14.04
```

I can open the `postgresql.conf` configuration file with `pgAdmin` but not the `pg_hba.conf` configuration file.

[image: pgAdmin III pg_hba.conf error message]

Both files are in the same directory (`/etc/postgresql/9.4/main`):

```
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  4641 Jun 10  2016 pg_hba.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 21501 Jun 10  2016 postgresql.conf
```

but I have noticed that the two configuration files have different permissions. I haven't modified the permissions of `pg_hba.conf` to make them different from those of `postgresql.conf`.

Are the permissions of these files different by default? Is there are reason why the `pg_hba.conf` has more restricted read permissions? Can I go ahead and modify the permissions of `pg_hba.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what is the point in doing that, but if you're an admin you can do `chmod o+r pg_hba.conf` to let a non-admin read it.

There are two ways in pgAdmin3 to access those files:

- by reading the file system (if it runs on the same host than the server). This corresponds to the `File->Open *.conf` commands. With that method, permission-wise, pgAdmin is not special, it's like a text editor or a pager.
- through the DB connection, with `Tools->Server configuration`. This requires the `adminpack` contrib module installed server-side. In the case of Ubuntu, I'm not sure it would work because the configuration files are not inside the data directory below `/var`, they're under `/etc/...` and the server-side functions involved are not supposed to reach anything outside the data directory. But if/when this method does work, it's the `postgres` process that reads the files, so the permissions shown in the question are good enough.

Comment: I was able to access the `pg_hba.conf` with pgAdmin reading the file system only *after* I gave `other` the `r`ead permission. Still not sure (& curious) why they were different in the first place. I am afraid `Tools → Server Configuration → pg_hba.conf` does not work with this set up. Which I find odd as I can work with `postgresql.conf` without any problems using both of the ways that you have outlined above.

Comment: as per your second point & this post https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/192CACC5E9234CADB2E08D69E91B343C%40andrusnotebook, it should not be possible to edit either `pg_hba.conf` or `postgresql.conf` so I'm finding this even odder. (The extension `adminpack` is installed in all the DBs.)